# Scrollbar causes Page to Move

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

For some reason, the scroll bar appearing will move everything a little bit left in Google Chrome.

Is this just me, or did this used to not happen?

Is there also a styling code or JavaScript that I can insert to prevent this from happening?

I already tried overflow:scroll; in my styles.css, however, I have put iframes of other files (I know, iframes are deprecated) and that causes scroll bars in the iframes.

Unless I can keep the overflow:scroll; or not have it apply to iframes, any help?

Many thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "move everything off the left"?

Comment: I mean that it moves everything left a bit.

Comment: Yes, that happens. Stupid as it is. There's no good way around it.

Comment: Well, that seems like a shame. I guess I have to live with it... Not good for a person with OCD, LOL.

Comment: @AirbusAi342 - Are you talking about how the scroll shorten the width of the window and shift the contents to the left side?

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm talking about.

Comment: can you provide a screenshot for that?

Comment: I cannot provide pictures in my posts; I'm apparently limited because I do not have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually makes sense rendering the HTML like that. Imagine you had, for whatever reason, a page with a vertical 5px bar on the right. If displaying the scrollbar wouldn't resize the rest, then this vertical bar would be hidden (by the scrollbar).
If scrollbars never are needed, I'd go with overflow: hidden. If the iframe-content is variable, I'd do an overflow-y: auto.
What might be interesting:
Chrome / Safari (WebKit) does indeed handle the scrollbar different from Firefox etc when it comes to media-queries. See: http://www.sitepoint.com/rwd-scrollbars-is-chrome-better/

Comment: Looks like I will have to do my best with these scroll bars... Thanks for the help.